# LTspice Frequency Response Analyzer (FRA)

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, buck

This post is a continuation of this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661864/how-to-measure-the-stability-of-a-buck-converter-using-ltspice?noredirect=1#comment1761137_661864).

LTspice recently introduced a new feature called frequency response analyzer, see the image below.

[image]

The green box shows the symbol for FRA. If you click on the FRA the second image pops up for configuring the FRA. Then if you click on 'Help me to configure this for a switching regulator', the third window comes.

I have some questions regarding the third window.

1. How do I get *Approximate Closed-Loop Bandwidth* of a switching regulator? Is this information available in the datasheet?
2. From where I will get *Approximate common mode voltage at FRA device*?

As per **Lars'** answer, the part circled in yellow is the rise time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [example AD circuit](https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice/w/faqs-docs/18464/generate-a-bode-plot-for-an-smps-in-ltspice-17-1) for the frequency response analyzer (FRA):
[image]

The FRA symbol is placed into the feedback path. The common-mode voltage at that point is the output voltage of the switching regulator, 5 V in this example.

For the closed loop bandwidth you could look into the datasheet for a typical transient response graph. This is from the [LT8618 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8618-8618-3_3.pdf) for example:
[image]

From the 10% to 90% rise time after the load step you can calculate the bandwidth:
$$BW = \frac{0.35}{t_{rise}}$$

My approximate reading from the graph is a rise time of 100 microseconds. This results in a bandwidth of 3.5 kHz which is relatively close to the data in the example:
[image]

Comment: Where does the value 0.35 come from ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it is an emperical estimation. You can find it in many books and websites.

Comment: @LarsHankeln,I updated the question.Could you please confirm my understanding is correct or not

Comment: @Hari Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Hari I updated the graph in my answer to clarify. To be precise, you would try to measure the 10% to 90% rise time to calculate bandwidth with the formula. But approximations should be fine for the FRA anyway.

Comment: @LarsHankeln,if the transient response curve is not given how do I will find closed loop bandwidth

Comment: @Hari You could also simulate a load step and watch the transient response in the simulation. If you want to use the FRA you will have a simulation model of the switching converter anyway.

Comment: @LarsHankeln,could you please show an example of  load step simulation.I am trying that but no proper result yet

Answer (score 0):

**Dr. Eric Bogatin** does a fantastic job of clearly explaining all things signal integrity and many related issues. He's a very down to earth, back to basics gentleman who obviously enjoys teaching Electrical Engineering. He makes learning interesting and fun.

Visit "https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/blogs/12-fundamentals/post/853-back-to-basics-bandwidth-and-rise-time" for his very clear derivation of the rough approximation BW = (0.35)/RT where BW = the highest frequency component of a signal, RT = the 10% to 90% rise time of that signal.

You might like to follow Dr. Bogatin's blogs, Rules of Thumb (really handy), ... .