# In LTspice, is there any way I can obtain the frequency response of power converter alone?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, frequency-response

I am aware of the following methods. But my intention is to understand the behavior of power converter alone, before adding the controller and feedback loop.

1. [FRA analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662057/ltspice-frequency-response-analyzer-fra): Provides the open loop frequency response (converter +controller) of a closed loop power converter.
2. [.AC analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/529501/38769): Works for averaged model, but need to develop the model.

Is there any way to get the equivalent of FRA analysis only for the converter section, without resorting to developing the average model?

Comment: Can you get the power stage running properly when you break the loop?

Comment: @Rohit Kilic: With constant Duty cycle and slight perturbation on it.

Comment: If the power converter has an input node and it has an output node then plot output/input but scaled for dB. It won't make a difference whether it's open-loop or closed-loop.

Comment: You can add small-signal analysis of the power stage and use a piece-wise linear (PWL) simulator like SIMPLIS or PSIM for extracting the ac response.

Answer (score 1):

There are many simulation tools to support FRA.

- **Simplis**, which use POP anaylis to find out DC steady point and give you open loop frequency response with ac analysis.https://www.simplistechnologies.com/
- **PSIM**, you can refer to video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZO4d86VtIs&ab_channel=AltairHyperWorksHow-To
  BTW, a small tool called **SmartCtrl** in PSIM also can support FRA and you can put pole and zero manually by click in the plot.
- **PLECS**, see the reference here:https://www.plexim.com/support/application-examples/187
- **LTpsice**, refer to LTspice help.
- **Pspice**(Candence tool)/**SaberRD**(Synopsys tool), both tools have FRA , but they will spend too much time to get result. Synopsys has released new PWL simulator named **SaberEXP**,but I can not afford it and never have a try, see the introduction here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNApbzFGcZ8&ab_channel=Synopsys